# How to override Material UI styles using classes using Emiotion

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am trying to override the default styles in a Mui component using the `classes` prop and passing the css into it.  So far I have been unsuccessful and I'm not sure what I have wrong.

The motivation for not using `makeStyles` is to keep our files cleaner and Emotion is faster.

I am able to do it successfully using `makeStyles` like this:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import HelpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Help';
import { Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { cbNeutral } from '../../src/theme/palette';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    arrow: {
        '&:before': {
            border: `1px solid ${cbNeutral[900]}`
        },
        color: cbNeutral[1000]
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: cbNeutral[1000],
        border: `1px solid ${cbNeutral[900]}`,
        color: cbNeutral[400],
        boxShadow: '0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(14, 13, 38, 0.12)',
        maxWidth: '385px',
        fontSize: '1.125rem',
        padding: '18px 25px',
        fontWeight: 400
    },
    root: {
        fill: cbNeutral[700],
        '&:hover': {
            fill: cbNeutral[400],
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    }
}));

const ToolTip = ({ text }) => {
    const styles = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setOpen(false)}>
            <Tooltip
                arrow
                title={text}
                placement="right-start"
                open={open}
                classes={{
                    arrow: styles.arrow,
                    tooltip: styles.tooltip
                }}
            >
                <HelpIcon onClick={() => setOpen(true)} classes={{ root: styles.root }} />
            </Tooltip>
        </ClickAwayListener>
    );
};

export default ToolTip;

ToolTip.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

I am trying to do it with Emotion like this:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import HelpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Help';
import { Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { cbNeutral } from '../../src/theme/palette';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const toolTipCss = css`
    .arrow {
        color: ${cbNeutral[1000]};
        &:before {
            border: 1px solid ${cbNeutral[900]};
        }
    }
    .tooltip {
        background-color: ${cbNeutral[1000]};
        border: 1px solid ${cbNeutral[900]};
        color: cbNeutral[400];
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(14, 13, 38, 0.12);
        max-width: 385px;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        padding: 18px 25px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .help-icon {
        fill: ${cbNeutral[700]};
        &:hover {
            fill: ${cbNeutral[400]};
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
`;

const ToolTip = ({ text }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div css={toolTipCss}>
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setOpen(false)}>
                <Tooltip
                    arrow
                    title={text}
                    placement="right-start"
                    open={open}
                    classes={{
                        arrow: 'arrow',
                        tooltip: 'tooltip'
                    }}
                >
                    <HelpIcon onClick={() => setOpen(true)} className="help-icon" />
                </Tooltip>
            </ClickAwayListener>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ToolTip;

ToolTip.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

In  that version where I use `className="help-icon"`, it works as expected, but `classes={{arrow: 'arrow', tooltip: 'tooltip'}}` does not change the default MUI styles.

I am using these versions of MUI and Emotion

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
```

I know we have it working like this in another app using older versions of MUI and emotion.  I don't know if something has changed in the mean time or of I just have something wrong with my syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.